# Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server on PHP Cloud + Zend Framework application

Tags: php, zend-framework, cloud

actually it is my first time to use Zend framework on phpcloud and i have successfully created a new Zend framework on my container.  But when I try to access different parts of the application (controller and actions / links / page), I get a "Not Found  The requested URL was not found on this server."

Answer (score 3):

In my .htaccess, I added a RewriteBase directive and this is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteBase /thefarm
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

where "/thefarm" is the name of the application deployed